# Use Select on Datatable/ Dataset

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm trying to get data from both Tables, where `Usage.ArticleId` equals `Article.idArticle`. Below are my Tables.

[image: My Datatables and their Connection]

I load the Dataset and Datatable like that:

```
DataSet1 = CType(Me.FindResource("DataSet1"), 
KleinteilContainerVerwaltung.DataSet1)
DataSet1.ReadXml(XMLPath)

Dim article As DataTable = DataSet1.Article
Dim usage As DataTable = DataSet1.Usage
```

Below is my attempt using LINQ. But the Select doesn't work.

```
Dim queryResults = From art In article
                       Group Join use In usage On
                       art.Field(Of Int32)("idArticle") Equals use.Field(Of Int32)("ArticleId")
                       Into _list = Group
                       Select art.Field(Of Int32)("Article")
```

And is there a way to use `art.idArticle` instead of `art.Field(Of Int32)("idArticle")`? And are there other ways instead of using LINQ?

Comment: The reason that you can't use properties the way you want is that you have declared your variables as just `DataTable` rather than the specific types contained in your typed `DataSet`.

Comment: Have you considered just adding an extra table adapter and `DataTable` to your `DataSet` that's based on a SQL query that joins the two database tables?

Comment: What do you mean by "the Select doesn't work"? It should work. You can use `art.idArticle` if you convert the `DataRow`s to `DynamicDataRow`s but then you just push everything to runtime.